# How to 'PasteSpecial' an enhanced metafile inline with text into Word from Excel?

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I'm trying to PasteSpecial an enhanced metafile into a Word bookmark, in-line with the text (as opposed to floating, which seems to be the default).  Specifically, my Word macro opens an Excel doc, copies a range of cells, and pastes into Word. I know there's a `wdInline` parameter, but I learned that that only works with an OLE object, unfortunately.

The only thing I've come across online is the idea of using "Shapes" - specifically, to use the `InlineShape` object - but I haven't found a way to alter my code to make that work.

```
Dim objExcel As New Excel.Application
Dim wb As Excel.Workbook
Dim uniqueIdentifier As String
Dim numRows As Long
Dim excelPath As String

Prompt1:
excelPath = InputBox("Enter directory/path to Excel Interface Catalogue")

If excelPath <> "" Then
Prompt2:
    uniqueIdentifier = InputBox("Enter the interface's Unique Identifier")
    uniqueIdentifier = UCase(uniqueIdentifier)

    If uniqueIdentifier <> "" Then
    Set wb = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(excelPath)

    wb.Sheets("API Data Fields").Range("G8").Value = uniqueIdentifier *[**Excel function populates the cells referenced in next line**]*
    numRows = (wb.Sheets("API Data Fields").Range("J8").Value) + 10
    wb.Sheets("API Data Fields").Range(wb.Sheets("API Data Fields").Cells(10, 7), wb.Sheets("API Data Fields").Cells(numRows, 10)).EntireRow.AutoFit
    wb.Sheets("API Data Fields").Range(wb.Sheets("API Data Fields").Cells(10, 7), wb.Sheets("API Data Fields").Cells(numRows, 10)).Copy
    ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("FieldDefinition").Range.PasteSpecial DataType:=wdPasteEnhancedMetafile
```

Comment: So what is working or not working? What exactly is the end result you're trying to achieve?

Comment: @PeterT Everything is working, in terms of general copying and pasting, but it pastes the image "floating" over the text.  I can go into the Word doc after the fact and right click and change the placement to "In line with text," and everything is perfect.  I'd just prefer to have it paste with this formatting, via the macro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as the Word version is not too old (not Word 2003) the [`PasteSpecial` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.word.selection.pastespecial?view=word-pia) has the argument `Placement`. This takes a `WdOLEPlacement` enum that determines how the object/graphical content is inserted: `wdFloatOverText` or `wdInLine`.

So...

```
ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("FieldDefinition").Range.PasteSpecial _
   DataType:=wdPasteEnhancedMetafile, Placement:=wdInLine
```

Comment: Thanks, but I've tried that.  That argument only works when the DataType is an OLE object.  I'm pasting enhanced metafile  See here:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.wdoleplacement
"Specifies the placement for an OLE object"

Comment: @PGord It works for me with that line of code, pasting a graphic. FWIW the default paste behavior is an Option in Word. If you feel you must, you can change that: `Options.PictureWrapType = wdWrapMergeInline`

Comment: I just tried it again, and it works.  Not sure what was going on before.  The only thing I changed was the order of the arguments.  Either way, thanks for the help!